# How to connect to Azure Table Service REST API?

Tags: rest, azure, storage, azure-api-apps

I'm working on trying to access an Azure table storage resource with REST API only from a .net application (without using the azure cloud libraries) ...

Just looking at the MSDN instructions, and get that my URL should be https://.table.core.windows.net/Tables to enumerate all the tables in the storage account, but when I enter the proper URL it gives me 404s...every URL I build according to the documentation to try and test functionality, comes back 404s.

I don't see where I can make the tables anonymous access in Azure, so I'm assuming I'm missing an authentication step somewhere, it's just not readily documented on MSDN.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Is URL really `//.table.core.windows.net`? You didn't include the storage account name?

Comment: David, I took out the table name in the list.  Should have included a placeholder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct - Anonymous table access is not possible.

For listing tables, the request needs to be authenticated. In order to have an authenticated request, you would need to create an authorization header and pass that header in your request. To create an authorization header, please see this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx